# How do you assign little text labels to the spots in MapBox GS JS, and assign hover/click info boxes to the same?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have this:

```
...
map.addSource('houses', { type: 'geojson', data: 'http://127.0.0.1/houses/houses.geojson' });
map.addLayer
({
    'id': 'houses-layer',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'houses',
    'paint':
    {
        'circle-radius': 8,
        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
        'circle-color': 'red',
        'circle-stroke-color': 'white'
    }
});
```

This puts a bunch of red spots on my map. Which is a good start. But I cannot figure out how to put a little text hovering above the red circles, and how to make it so that, if you either hover the mouse cursor above one of them, or click on one of them, it pops up an information box with more info.

How do you accomplish this? I've browsed the MapBox GS JS manual for so many hours and just never find anything other than by sheer accident.

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot figure out how to put a little text hovering above the red circles

Use a `symbol` layer with a `text-offset` value.

> if you either hover the mouse cursor above one of them

`map.on('mouseover', 'mytextlabels', e => ...)`

> or click on one of them

`map.on('click', 'mytextlabels', e => ...)`

> it pops up an information box with more info.

Use a `Popup`.

Comment: While I managed to figure out how to make "pop-up" labels, this answer did not help me whatsoever. It lacks any context and is so "incomplete" with each example as to be entirely meaningless, sadly.